# Excel help - Rearranging Columns

Tags: excel, excel-formula

So I need some help with excel.

What I have is in Black and what I need is in Red.

[image]

I have been able to rearrange column B to match column A and have it output in E but I need it to take the values in column C and D with it. This is what I have been using in column E:

`=IF(ISNA(VLOOKUP(A1,$B:$B,1,FALSE)), "Missing", A1)`

Can someone please help me figure out how to bring columns C and D with column B and populate them in F and G.

Any help is much appreciated! Thanks!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You were pretty close - Since this is a dynamic range, I would suggest using the `OFFSET()` function from a specific location in your spreadsheet.

So, here's the formula you could paste into cell `E1` and drag across / down to get the result you want:

```
=IFERROR(OFFSET($A$1,MATCH($A1,$B:$B,0)-1,COLUMN(A1)),"Missing")
```

Basically, what you're saying is:

- If I get an error in matching the value I want, print `Missing`:
  `=IFERROR(MATCH($A1,$B:$B,0),"Missing")`
- Move a set number of rows from cell `A1` based on where the numbers match with column A:
  `OFFSET($A$1,MATCH($A1,$B:$B,0)-1 ...`
- As I drag to the right, keep referencing the next column:
  `OFFSET($A$1,..., column(A1))`

Hope that helps explain it.

Comment: @pleasepleasehelpme, I added in some explanations in case they help you for the future with this kind of issue. Good luck.

Comment: Hey, it works but I can't seem to manipulate it. I have something in Column A already and "=IFERROR(OFFSET($B$1,MATCH($B1,$C:$C,0)-1,COLUMN(B1)),"Missing")" doesn't work. How do I adjust it accordingly? Thanks again!

Comment: Hey, So i can't ask another question and can't find this answer anywhere hoping you can come to my rescue again. If in cell A1 I have "$30 - $35" how can I copy the larger of the numbers into another cell , say B2 = "35". Without the dollar sign. Thanks!